# Finding the most active video maker within multiple tables(SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, subquery, sql-order-by

How can I find the `initials` of the most active video maker, the one that made the most videos considering the following tables using only one query?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Videos (
    title TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    video_description TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VideosMaker (
    full_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    initials TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VideosMaker_Videos (
    video_title TEXT NOT NULL,
    video_maker_name TEXT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (video_title, video_maker_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (video_title) REFERENCES Videos(title),
    FOREIGN KEY (video_maker_name) REFERENCES VideosMaker(full_name)
);
```

NOTE:
It is guaranteed that there will be only one video_maker who has contributed to a maximum number of news items.
For this problem, foreign_keys is ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the name of the video maker who made the most videos with this query:

```
SELECT video_maker_name
FROM VideosMaker_Videos
GROUP BY video_maker_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

and to get the initials you must use it as a subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT initials
FROM VideosMaker
WHERE full_name = (
  SELECT video_maker_name
  FROM VideosMaker_Videos
  GROUP BY video_maker_name
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Hmm... that is a bit weird, the platform I am sending it on says that I have non zero exit status: 9. I know it can have many many causes, but can I modify this line ` ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1` to something else? @forpas

Comment: @EsmerOmer Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=034189365719b49ba820829cd5d2abbd The query uses valid standard SQL code.

Comment: Done, I was writing something wrong. I mostly wrote the same query as you said but I was not very sure of the last part, GROUP BY and ORDER BY. I have solved the problem and I will document more on them. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about ties, so `order by` and `limit` is good enough here.

One option is to sort with a correlated subquery that computes the video count of each maker:

```
select vm.initials
from videosmaker vm
order by (
    select count(*) 
    from videosmaker_videos vmv 
    where vmv.video_maker_name = vm.full_name
) desc limit 1
```

This query should take advantage of the index on `videosmaker_videos(video_maker_name)`.

You can also join an aggregate subquery

```
select vm.initials
from videosmaker vm
inner join (
    select video_maker_name, count(*) cnt 
    from videosmaker_videos 
    group by video_maker_name
) vmv on vmv.video_maker_name = vm.full_name
order by vmv.cnt desc limit 1
```